# Word-for-word center-aligning of parellel lines of text in LaTeX?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, languages

I'd like to prepare a LaTeX document using a common format of displaying both Chinese characters and the corresponding romanization (pinyin) above each word.  For an example, please refer to [this page from a book](http://www.studychineseculture.com/wms/Upfiles/200881936956.jpg).

Note that, in the example picture, the romanized text above is centered between the characters below.  So, as in on the first line, it says "走读生" (one word, but 3 characters) and the corresponding pinyin text "\zou3\du2\sheng3" is centered above those 3 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about stackrel in mathmode? `$\stackrel{<chinese>}{<pinyin>}$`

Answer (score 1):

The package `covington` provides an easy way to gloss text. For example:

```
\gll Dit is een voorbeeldje in het Nederlands.
     This is a {little example} in {} Dutch.
\glend
```

The two sentences would be aligned word by word. You can align a group of words in one sentence with a single word in the other (cf. "voorbeeldje" and "little example"), or leave an empty space below/above a word (cf. "het").

See [Covington documentation](http://www.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/covington/covington/node9.html)